# Continuous progressbar in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

In the winforms we have a property called continuous that will show the progress bar from 0 till it hits 100.

I was looking for the same effect in WPF but from what I searched it leaded me to change the ***IsIndeterminate*** to true which doesnt give me the continuous effect only a weird effect of the part of the progressbar walking around.

To display an example of what I am talking about, the below image represents the continuous effect I am after:

[image: Ilustrative example]

Back to the question, how do I do that in WPF ?

Comment: I don't understand... isn't that what `ProgressBar` does by default without setting `IsIndeterminate`? Also, a continuous progress bar **is** an indeterminate progress bar. Perhaps take a look at [this Windows UX guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511486.aspx#determinateguidelines) for more info on determinate vs indeterminate.

Comment: @BoltClock partially yes but it is divided by blocks and is not continuos.

Comment: Looks like you're using Windows XP or the Classic theme in Vista/7 then.

Comment: @BoltClock yes windows xp and CodeNaked answered how to solve it by changing the theme thanks.

Comment: "weird effect of the part of the progressbar walking around"? It is so by convention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WPF ProgressBar does not have the Continous option. If you are on XP, or using the Luna themes, you will get the segmented look.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480371/whats-the-easiest-way-to-create-a-wpf-progress-bar-without-the-dashed-style) describes how the Aero theme can be applied, but otherwise you'd have to restyle the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the Progress bar to IsIndeterminate = false

```
var progress = new ProgressBar { Height = 50, Width = 300,  
                                 IsIndeterminate = false
                               };
```

I used that way and works as expected.
Are you updating the `Value` Property?

Update:
I think I know what you're problem is: WPF Controls renders differently in XP than Windows 7.
In Windows 7 works the way you want, but in XP, uses blocks

You're seeing this :

[image]
Instead of what you want :(

Comment: Markust that does not give the continuos effect but a segmented one.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly is the pictured progressbar continuous?

What is wrong is `IsIndeterminate`? What you describe as a "part of the progressbar walking around" is most suitable for a progress bar which does not have a definitive end, if you have a progress bar that fills up the user will expect that the operation is finished when the progress bar is completely filled, if it just starts over that might be quite annoying.

Comment: Because I want it to represent a health bar which cannot be walking around on it on :) hence why i need the continuos one.

Comment: From the other answers it became quite apparent that this is a styling problem, in the Aero theme it looks continuous dy default.